# Use .xcconfg values in .plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, xcconfig

We use a library that requires config values to be set in an `Okta.plist` file.

As our app has 3 environments, we have config per environment within `.xcconfig` files.

This allows us to set things like app icon, app name etc etc depending on the build type (dev, test, release).

I'd like to use those values within `Okta.plist` also, so I can configure the instance of Okta we use, however I can't seem to set those values using the config file.

In the case of our `Info.plist` we simple reference the value:

```
/// Release.xcconfig
...
APP_DISPLAY_NAME = Some Text
...
/// Info.plist
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${APP_DISPLAY_NAME}</string>
```

And it works.

How can I achieve the same with `Okta.plist`? I tried the same approach however it use the key as the value, not the value from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

All build settings(as declared in xcconfig files) are available as environment variables during the build phase script. Referencing those is only supported in `info.plist`, if you what to do this in any plist you must write a custom script that will perform the replacement and add it as a build phase script.
You can use the following script [Replaceplistenvironmentvariables.swift](https://gist.github.com/csknns/c6cdb90e1e2a8afff066c3fc0ebe1cff). This script takes an input & an output plist and will replace all reference to environment variables in the input plist with their value and write to the output plist.

Variable references must be in the following form:

```
<string>$(A_VARIABLE)</string>
```

To add this to our project follow the steps

- Download the Replaceplistenvironmentvariables.swift and place it in the top level of your project (no need to add a reference to the Xcode project)
- Add a new "run script phase" in the build phases
- Add the following line as a script

`/usr/bin/xcrun --sdk macosx swift "${PROJECT_DIR}/replacePlistEnvironmentVariables.swift" "${SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_0}" "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"`

- For "Input files" add the path to your plist e.g. `$(SRCROOT)/MyProject/Config.plist`
- For "Output files" add `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Config.plist`
- Make sure that your plist (e.g. Config.plist) is not added to your target, because the Xcode will complain two build commands produce the same output.